# NoMethodError: undefined method `with_deleted`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am trying to seed my database, but I am running into this error where its telling me `with_deleted` is an undefined method in my `seeds.rb`:

```
User.with_deleted.each(&:really_destroy!)
User.create(
  email: 'admin@example.com',
  roles: [:admin],
  password: 'abc123',
  password_confirmation: 'abc123',
)
```

I believe it should have been defined from the `paranoia` gem. Can anyone suggest a workaround? I am working in Rails 5.1.

I tried both of these:

```
@user = User.create(
      email: 'admin@example.com',
      roles: [:admin],
      password: 'abc123',
      password_confirmation: 'abc123',
    )
```

and

```
User.create(
   email: 'admin@example.com',
   roles: [:admin],
   password: 'abc123',
   password_confirmation: 'abc123',
)
```

and it looked like it worked but when I did a `User.last` in `rails c` I still got `nil`

As far as including `act_as_paranoid` in my `User.rb` file, this is what I have:

```
# acts_as_paranoid
include AddressFields
include MeAssessmentScoring
```

Is this not enough? But ultimately, can I just get this working without having to involve the `paranoia` gem? So far, what I have tried above has not worked and when I try to create a user within `rails c`, I get:

> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: First name can't be
>   blank, Last name can't be blank

when I ran this: `user = User.create!(email:'admin1@example.com', roles:'admin',password:'abc123', password_confirmation:'abc123')`

Comment: do you really need to destroy it? test db should be empty at the start. or you can delete it all if paranoid is not loaded User.delete_all or User.destroy_all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get up and running by executing the following:

```
heroku pg:backups:capture
heroku pg:backups:download
pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser -d thirdelementweb_development latest.dump
```